# Reduce time complexity to process sub-arrays

Tags: java, algorithm

For a given integer array of size n, find all possible sub arrays of size k which range from 1 to n.

Now find the common item which is also a minimum in all sub-arrays of size k, if no common item is found then use -1 and add that to the result list.

**For example:**

```
Input array : [4,3,3,4,2]
```

**Result :**

```
[-1,-1,3,3,2]
```

**Explanation:**

```
k = 1, [4],[3],[3],[4],[2], there is no common item so -1
k = 2, [4,3],[3,3],[3,4],[4,2], there is no common item so -1
k = 3, [4,3,3], [3,3,4], [3,4,2], common item is 3
k = 4, [4,3,3,4],[3,3,4,2], common items are 3 and 4, the minimum is 3
k = 5, [4,3,3,4,2], minimum common item is 2
```

This is my naive approach code along with comments:

```
public static List<Integer> solve(int[] ar) {
    // Get all subarrays in a map, with key as sub-arrays size from 1 to n and value as the corresponding sub-arrays 
    Map<Integer, List<List<Integer>>> map = subArrays(ar);
    int n = map.size();
    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        List<List<Integer>> list = map.get(i+1);
        // Get the common minimum item and store in result.
        result.add(solve(list));
    }
    return result;
}
// Logic to check for a given subarray of size k, get the minimum common item
public static int solve(List<List<Integer>> list) {
    int n = list.get(0).size();
    int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    boolean found = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int num = list.get(0).get(i);
        boolean isCommon = true;
        
        for(int j=1; j<list.size(); j++) {
            List<Integer> arr = list.get(j);
            if (!contains(arr, num)) {
                isCommon = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (isCommon) {
            min = Math.min(min, num);
            found = true;
        }
    }

    return found ? min : -1; // Return -1 if there is no common element.
}

// Logic to check if the number is present in given arr
public static boolean contains(List<Integer> arr, int num) {
    for (int value : arr) {
        if (value == num) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
// Logic to find all possible sub arrays of size 1 to n and stored in map
public static Map<Integer, List<List<Integer>>> subArrays(int[] arr) {
    int n = arr.length;
    Map<Integer, List<List<Integer>>> map = new HashMap<>();
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        map.put(i+1, new ArrayList<>());
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = i; j < n; j++) {
            int size = j - i+1;
            List<Integer> e = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int k = i; k <= j; k++) {
                e.add(arr[k]);
            }
            map.get(size).add(e);
        }
    }
    return map;
}
```

}

Here I am using a nested loop so time complexity is O(n^3), also using a map to store all possible sub-arrays that increase space complexity.

How to solve this in less time and less space.

**Update:**

I further tried to reduce time complexity using [below code](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/minimum-common-element-in-all-subarrays-of-size-k/):

```
public static List<Integer> solve(int[] ar) {
    int n = map.size();
    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        result.add(minCommonElementInSubarrays(ar, i+1));
    }
    return result;
}

static void minCommonElementInSubarrays(int arr[], int K) { 
    int N = arr.length;
    int c; 
   
    // If N is odd then update 
    // C as K >= (N + 1)/2 
    if ((N + 1) % 2 == 0) 
    { 
        c = (N + 1) / 2; 
    } 
   
    // If N is even then update 
    // C as K >= (N + 1)/2 + 1 
    else
    { 
        c = (N + 1) / 2 + 1; 
    } 
   
    // If K < C, return "=1" 
    if (K < c)
    { 
        return -1;
    } 
   
    // Otherwise 
    else
    { 
         
        // Initialize result variable 
        int ar = Integer.MAX_VALUE; 
   
        // Find minimum element 
        for(int i = N - K; i < K; i++)
        { 
            ar = Math.min(arr[i], ar); 
        } 
   
        // return the minimum value 
        return ar;
    } 
}
```

But still this code runs in O(n^2) time complexity, I want to reduce it further.

Comment: The improvement doesn't even compile. What in the 2nd `solve(int[] ar)` is `map`? I read the problem statement to require common *values*; the *improvement* is about *elements* included in all sub-arrays of a specified size: try `2, 1, 2, 1, 2`.

Answer (score 2):

As already explained by previous answer and comments the choice of solving the problem using just the `List` structure is questionable, for example taking your `[4,3,3,4,2]` input array and the value `k` = 3:

```
k = 3, [4,3,3], [3,3,4], [3,4,2], common item is 3
```

Every subarray can be obtained from the previous one in the chain deleting the first one element and adding the next one outside the window of length `k` or equivalently move the window of 1 element at every iteration:

```
input = [4, 3, 3, 4, 2]  k = 3

first  iteration: [4, 3, 3, 4, 2]   = [4, 3, 3]
                  [---k---]
second iteration: [4, 3, 3, 4, 2]   = [3, 3, 4]
                     [---k---]
third  iteration: [4, 3, 3, 4, 2]   = [3, 4, 2]
                        [---k---]
```

To find the mininum common element between these subarrays you can erase the duplicates and then compares the `Set` sets obtained from these subarrays:

```
input = [4, 3, 3, 4, 2]  k = 3

first  iteration: [4, 3, 3, 4, 2]   = [4, 3, 3] = {4, 3}
                  [---k---]

second iteration: [4, 3, 3, 4, 2]   = [3, 3, 4] = {3, 4}
                     [---k---]

{4, 3} ∩ {3, 4} = {3, 4}

third  iteration: [4, 3, 3, 4, 2]   = [3, 4, 2] = {3, 4, 2}
                        [---k---]

{3, 4} ∩ {3, 4, 2} = {3, 4}

Minimum is 3
```

You can so obtain a `List<Integer>` list from the first subarray of length `k` and its set, the next iterations will process the next subarrays and their sets doing the consecutive intersection; if one of the obtained sets after the intersection operation is empty the `-1` value will be returned otherwise the minimum will be returned.

```
 public class Exercise {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = {4, 3, 3, 4, 2};
        for (int k = 1; k <= arr.length; ++k) {
            System.out.println(solve(arr, k));
        }
        
    }
    
    public static int solve(int[] arr, int k) {
        //initialization of the first subarray and its set
        List<Integer> ints = IntStream.of(Arrays.copyOf(arr, k))
                .boxed()
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        Set<Integer> set = new TreeSet<>(ints);
        
        //consecutive subarrays and their sets with intersections
        for (int i = 1; i + k - 1 < arr.length; ++i) {
            ints.remove(0);
            ints.add(arr[i + k - 1]);
            //intersection with no need to create a set offered by jdk library
            set.retainAll(ints); 
            if (set.isEmpty()) { return -1; }
        }

        return Collections.min(set);
    }
}
```

I used just the built in data structures present in the jdk library, if you want to improve performance you have to build custom data structures.

Comment: @greybeard You are absolutely right.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a easier breakdown of this problem. One detail to consider about this problem is that other than the initial array, the sub-arrays only need to be considered a type of **Set** instead of **List**s. From there, at each step, you are `union`ing and `intersect`ing Sets to figure out the minimums.

To simplify this further, you could create a simple data structure that is a Set but also tracks the minimum of that set—let's call it a **MinSet**. When `union`ing two sets ***A*** and ***B***, the minimum of the result is just the smaller of the minimums of ***A*** and ***B***, which can be determined in constant time (not including the union itself). The intersection is trickier but can be done while the intersection is calculated.

This way, you can *reuse* the minimum calculation for the next **k**.

Comment: (Any comment on `if ((n + 2) / 2 < K) return -1;`?)

Comment: (I'm not sure I understand `The intersection is trickier but can be done while the intersection is calculated`.)